# Google pie chart attempts to draw before API finish loading

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am having some problem with Google chart. Here is the codes for my pie chart:

**EDITED PORTION**

```
function displayExistHospital(){
queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(overlayURLs["moh_hospital_WSA2"] + "/10");
query = new esri.tasks.Query();
query.returnGeometry = false;
query.where = "1=1";
query.outFields = ["*"];

queryTask.execute(query, getExistHospitalData);

document.getElementById("tabsLabel").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("tabsLabel3").innerHTML = "Age > 60";
document.getElementById("tabsLabel2").innerHTML = "SCPR";
document.getElementById("tabsLabel1").innerHTML = "Total Pop";

}
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: displayExistHospital});

var arrList = [];
function getExistHospitalData(results){
arrList = [];
var features = results.features;
dojo.forEach(features, function(feature){
var tempArr = [];
    var total_SCPR = feature.attributes.SUM_SUM_TOTAL_SCPR;
    var total_NR = feature.attributes.SUM_SUM_TOTAL_NR;
    var time = feature.attributes.FIRST_E_BREAK;
    tempArr.push(time,total_SCPR,total_NR);
    arrList.push(tempArr);
});

displayExistHospitalGraph(arrList); 
}

function displayExistHospitalGraph(arrListData){
var total_ten = parseInt(arrListData[0][1]) + parseInt(arrListData[0][2]);
var total_tentoFifteen = arrListData[1][1] + arrListData[1][2];
var total_fifteenTwenty = arrListData[2][1] + arrListData[2][2];
var total_greaterTwenty = arrListData[3][1] + arrListData[3][2];

var ppl_num = total_ten + total_tentoFifteen; 
var total_pop = total_ten + total_tentoFifteen + total_fifteenTwenty + total_greaterTwenty;
var dataOne = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Population', 'Percentage'],
    ['<10 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_ten,total_pop) , total_ten],
    ['10 - 15 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_tentoFifteen,total_pop), total_tentoFifteen],
    ['15 - 20 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_fifteenTwenty,total_pop), total_fifteenTwenty],
    ['>20 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_greaterTwenty,total_pop) , total_greaterTwenty],   
]);
var percentage = (((total_ten / total_pop) + (total_tentoFifteen / total_pop)) * 100).toFixed(1);
var title = "Total Population ("+total_pop.toLocaleString()+") Catchment By Drive-Time(Existing)";

var optionsOne = {
    chartArea: {
        width: 350,
        height: 200,
        top: 20, 
        left: 10 
    },
    fontName: 'Arial',
    fontSize: getFontSize(),
isStacked:false,
    title: title,
    width: 400,
height: 200,
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
    colors:['#004CA8','#437DC4','#96B8E0','#FFFFFF']
};

document.getElementById('hospitalBoxContent').innerHTML= "</br><p ><span style='font-size:2em; color:#00297A; font-family:ArialVerdana; font-weight:bold;'>"+percentage+"% ("+ppl_num.toLocaleString()+")</span > of residents stay within <span style='font-size:2em; color:#00297A; font-family:ArialVerdana; font-weight:bold;'>15-min</span> drive-time to a public hospital </p><br/>";
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('displayHospitalGraph'));
chart.draw(dataOne, optionsOne);

}
```

The chart works but somehow the percentage on the pie chart was cut off as the picture shown below:

[image]

I wonder is there any way to adjust the percentage for example, shift it nearer to the centre so that it won't cut off? I know the reason is because the chart was trying to draw before the API finish loading because this will only occur for the first load. After switching a few charts, the percentage label will be placed nicely inside the chart.

Credits to @asgallant and @Yoann as they helped me to spot the error but after added the codes, it still does not solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The shifted percent labels in the chart look reminiscent of one of three problems.  The first is a bug in Chrome (which may or may not have been fixed yet, I haven't checked), and is not something you can address.  The second is due to trying to draw the chart before the API has finished loading, and the third is due to drawing the chart inside a hidden div.  (continued...)

Comment: If your chart is drawn in or after the callback from the google loader is called, then you shouldn't have any issues with the second, and if you aren't drawing the chart inside a hidden div (I see this most often with people drawing charts inside tabs), then you shouldn't have any issues with the third.

Comment: @asgallant Exactly! It appears as the picture above only when the first load. After loading few charts, it's shifted nicely towards the centre. Do you have idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please change the last color #FFFFFF to any other color #FFFFFF this color is same as background

Comment: yes because color of showing percentage and last color is same so it cut of

Comment: But I have to use white color to display the percentage. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: I think I did not explain well, sorry about that. But what I mean is is it possible to shift the percentage to the center of the chart?

Comment: means you want show percentage to center of chart not towards edge

Comment: Yeah, exactly. It should move towards the centre. It just wont work properly for the first load somehow

Comment: you need to do manually inspect element with firebug there is text tag<text text-anchor="start" x="232.677" y="287.997.02" font-family="Arial" font-size="14" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff">8.3%</text> like this you need to add css and change value of x and y according to your requirement this will work there no any option in google chart to shift text to center

Answer (score 0):

Some elements are cut off in you screenshot.

- for the title, you need to increase top in optionsOne.chartArea (and height)
- for the legend, increase width or reduce left in optionsOne.chartArea
- the last pie item is set up on white colors:['#004CA8','#437DC4','#96B8E0','#FFFFFF'], change the font-colour or the last colour to avoid white on white

EDIT :

I created a http://jsfiddle.net/X24Sy/3/ with your code, I cannot reproduce your issue. Do you have any CSS for your container?

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart(){
        var total_ten=15,total_tentoFifteen=35,total_fifteenTwenty=50,total_greaterTwenty=10;
        var ppl_num = total_ten + total_tentoFifteen; 
        var total_pop = total_ten + total_tentoFifteen + total_fifteenTwenty + total_greaterTwenty;
        var dataOne = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Population', 'Percentage'],
            ['<10 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_ten,total_pop) , total_ten],
            ['10 - 15 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_tentoFifteen,total_pop), total_tentoFifteen],
            ['15 - 20 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_fifteenTwenty,total_pop), total_fifteenTwenty],
            ['>20 mins' +getPercentageInString(total_greaterTwenty,total_pop) , total_greaterTwenty],   
        ]);
        var percentage = (((total_ten / total_pop) + (total_tentoFifteen / total_pop)) * 100).toFixed(1);
        var title = "Total Population ("+total_pop.toLocaleString()+") Catchment By Drive-Time(Existing)";

        var optionsOne = {
            chartArea: {
                width: 350,
                height: 200,
                top: 20, 
                left: 10 
            },
            fontName: 'Arial',
            fontSize: 12,
            legend: { alignment: 'center', textStyle: { fontSize: 12} },
            // pieSliceText: 'none',       //label - > show the name on the pie
            tooltip: { 
                trigger: 'focus'// focus -> tooltip will be displayed when the user hovers over an element.
                // none -> tooltip is not displayed 
            }, 
            isStacked:false,
            title: title,
            width: 350,
            height: 200,
            sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
            colors:['#004CA8','#437DC4','#96B8E0','#FFFFFF']
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($('#displayHospitalGraph')[0]);
        chart.draw(dataOne, optionsOne);                            
    }
```

Comment: For the cut off one, what I mean is is it possible to shift the percentage to the center of the chart a little bit?

Comment: Nope I do not have. The percentage will shift towards the center after I loaded multiple charts. It just move to the edge during the first load.

Comment: Sorry but does your jsfiddle works? It's showing nothing in the result there

Comment: It looks like the google API is not loaded any more in Fiddle? Just have look to the top of the code for the load() and callback as asgallant mentioned above.

Comment: So you mean just add in the top two lines of codes?

Comment: Can you help me check the edited portion to see if there's anything went wrong?

Comment: edited portion? You need to Update the fiddle if you change anything and put link here please.

Comment: I just updated it. Would you mind to help me check if I am putting the codes at the correct places?

Comment: Yes, but when you update the URL change, can you provide the jsfiddle URL

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, what did you update? your question? the fiddleJS? your code?

Comment: Oh I see. The updated portion was at the top part inside this thread

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this:

```
function getExistHospitalData(results){
    arrList = [];
    var features = results.features;
    dojo.forEach(features, function(feature){
        var tempArr = [];
        var total_SCPR = feature.attributes.SUM_SUM_TOTAL_SCPR;
        var total_NR = feature.attributes.SUM_SUM_TOTAL_NR;
        var time = feature.attributes.FIRST_E_BREAK;
        tempArr.push(time,total_SCPR,total_NR);
        arrList.push(tempArr);
    });

    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(displayExistHospitalGraph(arrList));
}
```

First, you want to call `google.load` outside of any other functions.  Second, this line:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(displayExistHospitalGraph(arrList));
```

calls your `displayExistHospitalGraph` function with `arrList` as an argument, and passes it's return value (`null`) to `google.setOnLoadCallback`.  This means that your drawing function is being executed immediately, not in the callback.  Try this approach instead:

```
function getExistHospitalData(results){
    arrList = [];
    var features = results.features;
    dojo.forEach(features, function(feature){
        var tempArr = [];
        var total_SCPR = feature.attributes.SUM_SUM_TOTAL_SCPR;
        var total_NR = feature.attributes.SUM_SUM_TOTAL_NR;
        var time = feature.attributes.FIRST_E_BREAK;
        tempArr.push(time,total_SCPR,total_NR);
        arrList.push(tempArr);
    });

    displayExistHospitalGraph(arrList);
}
function init () {
    // get "results" and feed them to getExistHospitalData
    getExistHospitalData(results);
}
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"], callback: init});
```

Comment: I did it as my edited portion in this thread by following your guides but still does not work.

Comment: Can you post some example data returned by your query so I can test this?

Comment: Sorry, those data are confidential. I do not have the rights to release them. But are you okay with dummy values?

Comment: Any clues? Cause it still not fixed yet

Comment: Dummy values are fine, as long as they are in the same format as your real data.